# Cname and Amazon S3 failure

Tags: amazon-s3, cname-record, redundancy

I had a quick question. If you set up a cname for your amazon bucket and lets say your main amazon s3 bucket goes down, does cname you created serve files, in other words, do your files get redirected to cname if your main amazon s3 bucket goes down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CNAME just points to Amazon's servers. There's nothing there to serve files other than the S3 servers it's pointing at. If they go down, your CNAME won't be working.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I like direct answers:) I couldn't find a direct answer anywhere.